# Access Macro Converted to VBA then Editted only Executing Access Defined Code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have set up a basic macro where I export the contents of a table to excel. Macro works great, but now I want to create a check to see if the file name that I am saving to already exists, and if so, deletes that file so that I do not have the user deal with the prompt box asking if they would like to overwrite the file.

I converted the macro to VBA so that I could add in the desired dir(filename) and kill(filename) code. Once completed I was able to successfully run the code in the VBA editor, however, when I tried running the code based on the "on close" event of a form I have in access, it will only run the code as viewed in the access macro structure, as if I never added any additional lines of code in the VBA editor. Is there something that I was supposed to do to convert back from VBA to Access once I completed my edits?

Please see below for code that I would like to execute:

```
Function ExportLot()
On Error GoTo ExportLot_Err
Dim filename As String

    filename = "\\server1\Trial 
    Database for QS Reports\Lot Log Report.xlsx"
    DeleteFile (filename)
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "LLUnion", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", filename, False, "", , acExportQualityPrint

    ExportLot_Exit:
    Exit Function

ExportLot_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume ExportLot_Exit

End Function

Function FileExists(ByVal FileToTest As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = (Dir(FileToTest) <> "")
End Function

Sub DeleteFile(ByVal FileToDelete As String)
If FileExists(FileToDelete) Then 'See above
   ' First remove readonly attribute, if set
   SetAttr FileToDelete, vbNormal
   ' Then delete the file
   Kill FileToDelete
End If
End Sub
```

Original converted code (what currently runs when I call ExportLot from the form):

```
Function ExportLot()
On Error GoTo ExportLot_Err
Dim filename As String

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "LLUnion", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)","\\server1\Trial Database for QS Reports\Lot Log Report.xlsx", False,"", , acExportQualityPrint

    ExportLot_Exit:
    Exit Function

ExportLot_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume ExportLot_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: are you sure that your on close event refers to the new VB code and not to the original macro?

Comment: @DonGeorge Both the VBA code and the original access macro are titled the same. Am I wrong in thinking that the original macro made in Access and the editted code in VBA are linked?

Comment: Let's stop guessing please show us the OnClose event either as macro or VBA. We can then know what is being triggered.

Comment: @Parfait there is no OnClose Event to display in the method that I described above as I used the access form interface to select the code to run once the form was closed. But as highlighted by my answer below the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out either the solution to or a work around for this problem. I created a new macro (ExecuteCloseCode), and used the RunCode Event to call my function (ExportLot()) as defined in the question.

Then I used the on close event to call the "ExecuteCloseCode".

I am not sure why this method worked and my previously proposed efforts did not...

Comment: that's exactly what I meant in my prior comment - it sounds like your prior approach was executing the old macro and now, with this change, you are executing the new vba script (via the new macro).

Comment: Thanks @Don, my issue was with how to determine if I was running the old macro or if I was running the new macro.